# Exceljs return 'VERDADERO' instead 'TRUE'

Tags: node.js, excel, mongodb, mongoose, exceljs

I'm creating an app that uses import and export excel files, I need that excel returns in English `TRUE` and `FALSE` but instead returns `VERDADERO` and `FALSO` on the field `acceptTerms`, there is a way to export all in English, thanks

```js
async function generateExcel(req, res, next) {
  try {
    const ingresantes = await Ingresante.aggregate([
      {
        $project: {
          documentNumber: 1,
          codigo: 1,
          apellidos: 1,
          nombres: 1,
          email: 1,
          acceptTerms: 1,
        },
      },
    ]);

    var workbook = new Excel.Workbook();
    var worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet("subida");

    worksheet.columns = [
      { header: "DNI", key: "documentNumber", width: 10 },
      { header: "CODIGO", key: "codigo", width: 10 },
      { header: "APELLIDOS", key: "apellidos", width: 20 },
      { header: "NOMBRES", key: "nombres", width: 20 },
      { header: "CORREO", key: "email", width: 35 },
      { header: "ESTOY_CONFORME", key: "acceptTerms", width: 25 },
    ];

    ingresantes.map((data, index) => {
      data.nro = ++index;
      worksheet.addRow(data);
    });

    worksheet.getRow(1).eachCell((cell) => {
      cell.font = { bold: true };
    });

    var tempFilePath = tempfile(".xlsx");

    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile(tempFilePath);
    await res.status(200).sendFile(tempFilePath);
  } catch (err) {
    next(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Which data is shown as `VERDADERO`? Are you sure it's not related to the fact that you're opening the XLSX file in a Spanish locale version of Excel?

Comment: Do an edit find / replace of verdadero with true.

Comment: thaks @msbit its that, I changed to xlsx to English and now returns the boolean values in English; It's an option too 'solar-mike'